# SDL_DisplayFormat crashes with initializer_list

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a struct that I am initializing using a list of filepath strings. However, if I try to call SDL_DisplayFormat on the SDL_Surfaces created from these strings, the application won't start. It doesn't crash and it doesn't generate stdout.txt or stderr.txt like normal, it just doesn't start. The compiler doesn't give any errors or warnings. This is my code:

```
struct Object {

    std::vector<SDL_Surface*> surfaceVector;

    Object(initializer_list<std::string> init) {
        for (auto i : init) {
            SDL_Surface* loadSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(i.c_str());
            surfaceVector.push_back(SDL_DisplayFormat(loadSurface););
            SDL_FreeSurface(loadSurface);
        }
    }

}
```

If I don't call SDL_DisplayFormat, I can access and blit the surfaces in surfaceVector like normal, so they seem to be loading properly. However, I want the surfaces in surfaceVector to be in display format.

Comment: Have you checked if the return value of `SDL_DisplayFormat(loadSurface) `is null?

Comment: I haven't been able to since the application won't actually start, so I can't print or do anything like that. However, if I remove SDL_DisplaySurface() and add some code like if (loadSurface == NULL) cout << "null" else cout << "not null"; then it still runs but won't print anything, and stdout.txt won't generate no matter how many cout statements I have elsewhere. So I've probably done something weird somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SDL2, try using `SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat()` instead of `SDL_DisplayFormat()`.

SDL's wiki page on [SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29).